Word Ribbon Action Function Is Not Triggered
I am working in an add-in project using taskpane. I created a custom tab and identified my buttons and function actions in the manifest file as described:
    <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=276812"/>
        <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html"/>
      </bt:Urls>
                <Label resid="Aproove.Tab1.GroupLabelSettings" />

                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                </Icon>

                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="Aproove.SettingsButton">
                  <Label resid="Aproove.SettingsButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="Aproove.SettingsButton.Label" />
                    <Description resid="Aproove.SettingsButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>sayHi</FunctionName>
                     <SourceLocation resid="Commands.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>



and specified the commands.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />

    <!-- Office JavaScript API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js"></script>

    <script>

(function () {
    Office.initialize = function () {
        console.log('yes, i have inited')
    };
})();
        function sayHi(event) {
            window.alert('hi!');
            event.completed();
        }
    </script>
    
</head>

<body>
  
</body>

</html>


When I click on the "settings" button in the custom tab ribbon, nothing happened. Even the initialization of the office with its logs are not triggered.
I tried to make logs inside the script, but the whole page (I Guess ?) is not loaded

You have to have a <FunctionFile> element in the manifest that points to the file with the action method. It should be the first child under the <DesktopFormFactor> element (or the second if you have a <GetStarted> element). Here's an example.
<DesktopFormFactor>
    <GetStarted>
      ...
    </GetStarted>
    <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url" />
    ...
</DesktopFormFactor>


If you haven't already, please take a look at Create add-in commands.
